# Fixed and Variable Column Widths (Table or Float)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a 3 column, full width page but I want to have 2 columns a fixed width and the other one will fit full width between them, like so:

```
| Fixed Width || Variable Width                || Fixed Width        |
| Always Left || Adapts To Browser Window Size || Always Fixed Right |
```

I tried it with float which didn't work and then someone suggested using display-table which worked until I had to edit the page slightly.  Now the right hand column is ok but the 2 left columns have content right down at the bottom and not at the top where it needs to be.  Can anyone please help with this. Here is the code that I am using:

```
    .pageContent{
        background-color: #DADEE1;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
    .gridSystem{
        display: table;
    }
    section{
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .mainSidebar{
        float: left;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 140px;
    }
    .mainPage{
        width: inherit;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .mainAdvert{
        float: right;
        width: 140px;
    }

<div class="pageContent gridSystem">
    <section class="mainSidebar"></section>
    <section class="mainPage"></section>
    <section class="mainAdvert"></section>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it need to be in CSS?

Comment: I guess not as long as there's a suitable alternative to work in ALL major browsers.  I should also add that .mainPage will contain a JQuery masonry style grid.

Comment: Updated everything. Check it again now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Jquery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window_width = $(window).width;
    mainPage_width = window_width - 140 - 140; 
    $(".mainPage").width = mainPage_width + "px";    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/_rov/zBF3j/

Comment: Thaks but as you may notice from the code I gave, it's the .mainPage I want to be full width and not limited!

Comment: Thanks, the css version is putting the .mainPage beneath the .mainSidebar

Comment: Not sure about the CSS solution then. But I'm sure the Jquery solution is working for all browsers.

Comment: I'm just wondering how wrong it would be to use a table and td in this situation as it is an easy and working solution. What is the word on tables in html these days? Is it still frowned upon, lol

Comment: Even if it's just to get the 3 columns working? I've never quite understood the reason behind not using tables for this kind of structure, I mean you can use CSS within the tables can't you?

Comment: It means that you shouldn't use them at all.

Comment: I know what it means but I just don't understand it as it's the solution that works well and is evtremely easy to do with No CSS or JQuery trickery but I'll try the JQuery way.  The problem for me is that I like the idea of the .mainPage being able to move automatically as a browser window is restored down, JQuery will not do this without further code being added.

Answer (score 0):

Because the left column (mainSidebar) is fixed, you know the point where column 2 (mainPage) starts...  then use jQuery to set the width (or any other css)...  Agreed with Rov - I don't think CSS can account for various screens - so best use jQuery / Javascript.